# Asp.net postback is firing javascript should on be on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I found some Javascript that uploads files it works wonderfully. However When I added a search on the asp.net page it fires a postback that clears the files. This is the line that keeps firing $(document).on("click", "#attachedfiles tr", function ()
I've tried "load","ready" And .one the postback always fires the javascript.
What should be used to ensure the javascript only fires on the intial page load only? Here is the full script.

```
    $(function () {

        var fileExt = "";

        var fileDesc = "";

        fileExt = "*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;";

        fileDesc = "Allowed Files ";

        fileExt += "*.mp3;*.wav";

        fileExt += "*.flv;*.mpg;*.mp4;*.avi";

        fileExt += "*.html,*.htm,*.doc;*.docx;*.pdf;*.rtf;*.txt,*.csv,*.xsl;*.xslx";

        $("[id*=FileUpload1]").uploadify({

            'swf': 'scripts/uploadify.swf',

            'buttonText': 'Attach Files',

            'uploader': 'uploadVB.ashx?key=<%=Key %>',

            'method': 'post',

            'fileSizeLimit': '12MB',

            'fileTypeDesc': fileDesc,

            'fileTypeExts': fileExt,

            'multi': true,

            'auto': true,

            'onSelect': function (event, ID) {

                $('#btnSendx0').prop('disabled', true);

                $("#attachedfiles tr").each(function () {

                    if ($("td", this).eq(0).html() == event.name) {

                        alert(event.name + " already uploaded.");

                        $('#btnSendx0').prop('disabled', false);

                        $("#FileUpload1").uploadify('cancel');

                        return;

                    }

                });

            },

            'onUploadComplete': function (event, ID, file, response, data) {

                $('#btnSendx0').prop('disabled', false);

                $("#attachedfiles").append("<tr class='someclass'><td>" + event.name + "</td><td><a href='javascript:;' >[x]</a></td></tr>");

            }

        });

    });



    $(document).on("click", "#attachedfiles tr", function () {

        console.log($(this).attr('someclass'));

        var row = $(this).closest("tr");

        var fileName = $(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(0).html();

        var href = $(this).find("a").attr("href");

        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",

            url: "sendEmails.aspx/RemoveFile",

            data: '{fileName: "' + fileName + '", key: "<%=Key %>" }',

                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

                    dataType: "json",

                    success: function () { },

                    failure: function (response) {

                        alert(response.d);

                    }

                });

                row.remove();

            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you're missing a point: everytime that there's a postback, the HTML page is loaded again. HTML is stateless, but with the use of POST and ViewState, ASP.NET simulates a statefull HTML. 
This could be messy: you think that the page is not fully loaded but instead it is, and the data is refilled each time the request is done by a runat="server" element (except for updatepanel and other ajax-friendly controls) with the same data that you had before the request.

So the point is that HTML (and javascript executes when HTML is interpreted by browsers),  cannot "directly" know if it's the first time or the x time that is loaded (theorically by the referrer this could be obtained, but developing a proper logic for this issue... and this have nothing to do with PostBack or other ASP.NET mechanisms).

To answer at your question, try to render the script only when is not a postback, create a protected string loadInitialScript() method in the page and return the script as a string if is not a postback, string.Empty elseway. Then in your script tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript>
    <%=loadInitialScript()%>
</script>
```

so if is a postback, the loadInitialScript method will return an empty string, else it will return the javascript function (I suggest to use $(document).on("ready")) and it will be executed.